# Cannot install tomcat8 with apt

Tags: apt, tomcat8

I cannot install tomcat8 with apt on Ubuntu 16.04. sudo apt install does not find tomcat8 at all. It looks like my apt is messed up. Any ideas how to solve this?

My sources.list is

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial restricted main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial restricted multiverse universe main #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates restricted main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates restricted multiverse universe main #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports restricted universe multiverse main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports restricted universe multiverse main #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security restricted main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security restricted multiverse universe main #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
```

and /var/lib/apt/lists looks like

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Okt 19 14:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root    4096 Okt 19 13:07 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   11474 Okt  9 18:29 archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9544 Okt  9 18:29 archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_partner_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     699 Aug 21 21:26 archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_partner_binary-arm64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    9522 Okt  9 18:29 archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_partner_binary-i386_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4228 Jul  1  2017 archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_partner_i18n_Translation-en
-rw-r----- 1 root root       0 Okt 19 14:03 lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1974976 Okt 19 00:38 maven.xwiki.org_stable_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1308 Okt 19 00:38 maven.xwiki.org_stable_Release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     198 Okt 19 00:38 maven.xwiki.org_stable_Release.gpg
drwx------ 2 _apt root   28672 Okt 19 14:03 partial
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17535 Okt 19 13:54 ppa.launchpad.net_geonode_testing_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   81040 Apr  3  2018 ppa.launchpad.net_geonode_testing_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   77911 Apr  3  2018 ppa.launchpad.net_geonode_testing_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-arm64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   80330 Apr  3  2018 ppa.launchpad.net_geonode_testing_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   88735 Mär 30  2018 ppa.launchpad.net_geonode_testing_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18050 Mai 20  2016 ppa.launchpad.net_jonathonf_antlr3_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18077 Feb 11  2017 ppa.launchpad.net_jonathonf_jruby-builddeps_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10234 Feb 11  2017 ppa.launchpad.net_jonathonf_jruby-builddeps_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10234 Feb 11  2017 ppa.launchpad.net_jonathonf_jruby-builddeps_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-arm64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   10234 Feb 11  2017 ppa.launchpad.net_jonathonf_jruby-builddeps_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8534 Feb 11  2017 ppa.launchpad.net_jonathonf_jruby-builddeps_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   15451 Okt 17 17:43 ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_trusty_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5323 Okt 17 17:43 ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5323 Okt 17 17:43 ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-arm64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5323 Okt 17 17:43 ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1678 Okt 17 17:43 ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1278 Okt 17 17:43 ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_source_Sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17540 Okt 17 17:09 ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5323 Okt 17 17:09 ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5323 Okt 17 17:09 ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-arm64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5323 Okt 17 17:09 ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1678 Apr 19  2018 ppa.launchpad.net_webupd8team_java_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en
```

From sudo apt update I get

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freeipa/staging/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Ign:6 http://maven.xwiki.org stable/ InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/geonode/testing/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://maven.xwiki.org stable/ Release
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/antlr3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/jruby-builddeps/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freeipa/staging/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Sources [2.528 B]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Sources [8.384 B]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Sources [224 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources [323 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [7.556 B]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages [7.524 B]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en [2.272 B]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [157 B]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [862 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [772 kB]
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [351 kB]
Get:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources [136 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [320 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [230 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [694 kB]
Get:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Sources [2.116 B]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [636 kB]
Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources [78,4 kB]
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Sources [2.088 B]
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Get:38 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [570 kB]
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [281 kB]
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [247 kB]
Get:41 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [491 kB]
Ign:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
Get:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [239 kB]
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [333 kB]
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [16,4 kB]
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15,5 kB]
Ign:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en [8.344 B]
Get:49 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [67,7 kB]
Get:50 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [68,0 kB]
Get:51 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [7.204 B]
Get:52 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages [7.224 B]
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5.960 B]
Get:54 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en [2.152 B]
Get:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [14,3 kB]
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages
Get:56 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [200 B]
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Get:57 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [392 kB]
Get:58 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [340 kB]
Ign:59 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:60 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [150 kB]
Get:61 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [108 kB]
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Get:62 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [145 kB]
Get:63 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3.460 B]
Get:64 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3.632 B]
Ign:65 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Get:66 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en [1.744 B]
Get:67 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]
Get:68 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Ign:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Get:69 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Sources [6.740 B]
Get:70 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Sources [4.868 B]
Get:71 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [194 B]
Get:72 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [7.804 B]
Get:73 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages [7.488 B]
Ign:59 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:65 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:74 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Get:75 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en [4.184 B]
Get:76 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5.104 B]
Get:77 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [1.789 B]
Ign:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:59 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:78 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [216 B]
Get:79 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Get:80 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [7.304 B]
Get:81 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages [7.300 B]
Ign:82 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
Get:83 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en [4.456 B]
Ign:65 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Err:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Get:84 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3.328 B]
Get:85 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Err:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:59 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:65 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:74 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Get:86 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Sources [2.116 B]
Get:87 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Sources [2.088 B]
Get:88 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Sources [78,4 kB]
Get:89 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources [136 kB]
Get:90 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [7.204 B]
Get:91 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages [7.224 B]
Get:92 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en [2.152 B]
Get:93 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [200 B]
Get:94 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [570 kB]
Get:95 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [491 kB]
Ign:96 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
Get:97 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [239 kB]
Get:98 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [67,7 kB]
Get:99 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [68,0 kB]
Get:100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [392 kB]
Get:101 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [340 kB]
Ign:102 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:103 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [150 kB]
Get:104 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [108 kB]
Get:105 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [145 kB]
Get:106 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3.460 B]
Get:107 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3.632 B]
Ign:108 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Get:109 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en [1.744 B]
Get:110 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]
Get:111 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Ign:82 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
Ign:74 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:96 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
Get:112 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Sources [4.808 B]
Get:113 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Sources [179 kB]
Get:114 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Sources [7.728 kB]
Get:115 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Sources [868 kB]
Get:116 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [8.344 B]
Get:117 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages [8.684 B]
Get:118 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en [2.908 B]
Get:119 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [186 B]
Get:120 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1.201 kB]
Get:121 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [1.196 kB]
Ign:122 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
Get:123 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [568 kB]
Get:124 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [733 kB]
Get:125 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [409 kB]
Get:126 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [7.532 kB]
Get:127 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages [7.512 kB]
Ign:128 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Get:129 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en [4.354 kB]
Get:130 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3.410 kB]
Get:131 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7.448 kB]
Get:132 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]
Get:133 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages [140 kB]
Ign:134 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Get:135 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en [106 kB]
Get:136 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [63,8 kB]
Get:137 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [230 kB]
Ign:102 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:108 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:82 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
Err:74 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Ign:96 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:122 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
Ign:128 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:134 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:102 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:108 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:82 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
Err:96 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Ign:122 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
Ign:128 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:134 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:102 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:108 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse arm64 Packages
Err:122 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Ign:128 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:134 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Reading package lists...
```

Comment: [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804) my help.